# How to manipulate long-table data for correlations, using dplyr, but without transposing data to wide format

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have some data which represents repeated (session A and B) measurements (var.x) of patients (id). My data is tidy (i.e. long-form table with one variable in each column and one observation in each row) ... like so:

```
| id | var.1 | var.2 | session |
--------------------------------
|  1 |  1.1  |   11  |    A    |
|  1 |  1.9  |   12  |    B    |
|  2 |  1.2  |   15  |    A    |
|  2 |  1.4  |   14  |    B    |
```

I want to do a correlation analysis of paired (by id) data (e.g. var.1) from session A and B. In other words, what is the correlation coefficient between repeated measurements..

This is not difficult to do, if I tranpose/pivot/melt/spread the data into a wide format like so:

```
| id | var.1.A | var.2.A | var.1.B | var.2.B |
----------------------------------------------
|  1 |  1.1    |   11    |   1.9   |   12    |
|  2 |  1.2    |   15    |   1.4   |   14    |
```

...then I can simply cor(var.1.A, var.1.B). And I realize that dplyr/tidyr have gather/spread/separate/unite commands for that purpose, however this seems untidy and less than elegant to me as I basically have to copy my data.

Is there a way to do this using dplyr, without reshaping the data?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
data %>% 
    select(id, var.1, session) %>%
    do( cor( filter(session=='A', filter(session=='B'))
```

...but obviously this doesn't work and I also need to somehow specify, that the data is paired (by id).

Comment: Try `data %>% select(id, var.1, session) %>% do({data.frame(Cor=cor(.$var.1[.$session=='A'], .$var.1[.$session=='B']))})`  If you need to do this by 'id', use `group_by` after `select`

Comment: If you are using `data.table` `setDT(data)[, Map(function(x,y) cor(x[y=='A'], x[y=='B']), .SD[, c('var.1', 'var.2'), with=FALSE], list(session))   ]`

Comment: Any operation you will do will make a temporary copy of your data in the memory. Converting your data to a wide format will be probably more efficient and concise then running by row/column operations. You don't have to store the wide format anywhere, rather just run some operations until you reach desired output and it will be wiped out from memory by itself.

Comment: I was under the impression, that dplyr generally manages to index data in an efficient way, rather than duplicate it. But in any case, duplicating the data can only introduce opportunities to make a mess of the data :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try either `dplyr` or `data.table` methods.  Assuming that we want to find the correlation for the 'var' columns, we create an index of the columns using `grep` ('nm1'), and a custom function (`f1`).  We use `Map` within `do` for getting the `cor` of each 'var' column.  We use the 'var' columns as first input i.e. 'x' and 'session' as the 'y'.

```
nm1 <- grep('^var', names(data))
f1 <- function(x,y) cor(x[y=='A'], x[y=='B']) 
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
      do({data.frame(Map(f1, .[nm1], list(.$session)))})
#   var.1 var.2
#1    -1     1
```

---

In a similar way, we can do the `cor` using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, Map(f1, .SD[, nm1, with=FALSE], list(session)) ]
#   var.1 var.2
#1:    -1     1
```

---

If we are using `base R`

```
mapply(f1, data[nm1], list(data$session))
# var.1 var.2 
# -1     1
```

---

If we want to convert to `wide` format, we can use `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5` as it can take multiple `value.var` columns.

```
 dW <- dcast(setDT(data), id~session, value.var=c('var.1', 'var.2'))[, id:=NULL]
 dW
 #   var.1_A var.1_B var.2_A var.2_B
 #1:     1.1     1.9      11      12
 #2:     1.2     1.4      15      14
```

We can convert to `matrix`, subset, apply `cor` and get the `diag` values.

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(dW)
 diag(cor(m1[,c(TRUE, FALSE)], m1[,c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
 #[1] -1  1
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), var.1 = c(1.1, 1.9, 1.2, 
1.4), var.2 = c(11L, 12L, 15L, 14L), session = c("A", "B", "A", 
"B")), .Names = c("id", "var.1", "var.2", "session"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I ran into a few problems, such as rows with an A session and no corresponding B session ... but that's been sorted.

However, more importantly: does the first solution consider the paired nature of the data or simply correlate the two sets (A and B), based on the order of rows?

Comment: @SørenONeill  In your dataset, there is only a pair of observations for each ID.  In the solutions given above, I am just doing the cor for the elements corresponding to 'A' with that of 'B'.  It may be useful to show a bit more complex data and the expected output.

Comment: If I understand your code, the function isolates the var data from session A and similarly from session B (producing in essence two vectors), which are then correlated .. however the pairing of those vector values will depend on the order of the values, not necessarily being coupled by the id.
Thats what I mean by paired correlation in relation to the id and that is why reshaping the data into a wide format is an easy solution -- because it easily retains the id-coupling of the repeated A/B measurements.
Perhaps, what were leaning towards now, is simply reshaping a selected number of columns?

Comment: @SørenONeill  If we look at the results of wide and long format, it is basically the same.  Perhaps a better example will be useful to test.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd add an answer showing how to do this using `summarise_each` from *dplyr*.

This approach is dependent on the dataset order.  In a case like this I like to use `arrange` to make sure the dataset is in the desired order, although this can be skipped if your are confident things are already in order.

```
data %>%
    arrange(id, session) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(cor(.[session == "A"], .[session == "B"])), starts_with("var"))

  var.1 var.2
1    -1     1
```

In `summarise_each`, the `.` refers to the variable you are summarizing, where in `do` it refers to the dataset.

You can simply write out the variables you want to summarize by name, but I used the function `starts_with` to pick the variables.  See the help page for `select` for more on these special functions.

You also will need to make sure you have a pair within each ID.  The `complete` function from package *tidyr* may be useful if you run into a situation where one of the `session` levels is missing within an `id`.  If this is the case, you'll likely need to make use of `use` argument in `cor`.